# Add dependent setup fee to product

Tags: product, price, custom-options

I have a type of product that needs a "setup fee" that depends on a selection of a custom option.

I tried to set a price for the custom option but the problem is that this price is multipled by the quantity.

What I'm looking for is:

- product A costs **X**
- product A plus option costs **X + FEE**
- N product A with option costs **(N * X) + FEE**

Any solution?

Comment: Can this help? https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I've created an extension that using observers on sales_quote_* events it adds or removes a special "fee" product to the customer cart based on the product/s added or removed from the cart.

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom product attribute for products that have a setup fee that contains the setup fee. Then create a module with a final price observer and the logic to detect if the product has a setup fee and add that to the final price calculation for that product.

Comment: I can make an observer on `catalog_product_get_final_price` but this event is dispatched everywhere a price is shown, could you address me on how to add the fee only when a customer select a specific value of a specific custom option (like the customer select "wood" value of a custom option named "frame")?

Comment: How about you make product A a bundle product and add the options, 'wood', 'frame' as bundle items. You can then manually specify the quantity of the bundle item as 1 so that it is charged only one time.